# Bind a function to an Element in a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to recreate a calculator I made in Angular using React. I found recreating the html was not too difficult, but I'm having an issue with binding onclick events inside a looped Element.

Here's the element I want to recreate:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render(){
     return <div onClick={this.props.func} className="calc-button">{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here's where I want it to loop and bind a function to the button.

```
class OperationsBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = objButton;
    this.numClick = this.numClick.bind(this);}
  numClick(){
    console.log("5") 
  }

  render(){
    var rows = [];
    this.state.button.forEach(function(button,index){
    var row  = button.map(function(obj, index2)
    {
       if(index===4){
          return <div className="calc-button clear">{obj.value}</div>;
    }
    return(<Button 
            func={this.numClick.bind(this, index2)} 
            value={obj.value}
            />);
            }.bind(this))
     rows.push(row)})

return <div className="operations-box">
   <div className="calc-row">{rows[0]}</div>
   <div className="calc-row">{rows[1]}</div>
   <div className="calc-row">{rows[2]}</div>
   <div className="calc-row">{rows[3]}</div>
   <div className="calc-row">{rows[4]}</div>
   </div>;
  }
}
```

It constantly says the numClick is undefined.

Here's the link to my React Calc

http://codepen.io/awronka/pen/XmyQxB?editors=001

Here's my link to my working Angular Calc

http://codepen.io/awronka/pen/yYeLdp

Comment: Try to fix your indentation. It then should be pretty obvious that you've bound only one of your two loop callbacks. With ES6, you should switch to arrow functions anyway.

Comment: Objbutton is an object that contains a list of values that I want displayed on the button objects.

Comment: Bergi, can you further explain that I've only bound one of the loop callbacks. I'm not completely clear on that

Comment: You have `.forEach` and `.map`, but you only bind the callback passed to `.map`. What do you expect `this` inside the `.forEach` callback to be?